# How can I see the content of global arguments or methods in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

i am learning javascript, and thougth it would be cool to know how things actually work behind the scenes.

I actually gone to the the console and typed

`console.log(Promise);`

but this is what it returned.

```
all: ƒ all()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: "all"
[[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
allSettled: ƒ allSettled()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: "allSettled"
[[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
apply: ƒ apply()
arguments: (...)
bind: ƒ bind()
call: ƒ call()
caller: (...)
constructor: ƒ Function()
length: 0
name: ""
toString: ƒ toString()
Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance): ƒ [Symbol.hasInstance]()
get arguments: ƒ ()
set arguments: ƒ ()
get caller: ƒ ()
set caller: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: ​
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
any: ƒ any()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: "Promise"
```

is there any way to see those methods in the way we write code, so that I could get a better understanding?.

Comment: Built-in functions are in the browser's source code, you can't see the details in the console.

Comment: As an alternative you can always check out documentations of these methods/properties (for example, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)), which will give you enough information to understand them thoroughly.